# How to call Google Analytics script from dynamically generated ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I have a number of cases in my ASP.NET MVC web app where I return a dynamic result (ContentResult which returns an rss feed in this case) from a controller action method rather than a view.  In these cases how can I implement Google Analytics tracking?

Comment: If all else fails you can always use the measurement protocol: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include JavaScript-based tracking into RSS file, because as far as I can see from [specification](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html), there is no way to include JavaScript code/link into it.

As Matt explained, you need to use measurement protocol from Google or something similar and perform web request from your MVC action. This, however, will increase load on your web server. There are 2 other disadvantages with server-side tracking:

1. You will not be able to track additional information with this method like visit duration, bounce rate etc.
2. RSS is frequently downloaded by automatic tools and you stats will be very misleading.

You should consider those limitations when implementing your server-side tracking.